# How to get 24V and 1A output from 12V battery car

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter

i have an antenna that works with 24v and 1A, and i need to make it working with a battery car of 12V 8Ah or 7Ah.

is this possible or do you have any options?

Comment: `Ah (Ampere-hour)` is not the same as `A (Ampere)`.

Comment: yes it an ordinary battery car so what do you suggest?

Comment: Buy a 12V to 24V DC/DC converter.

Comment: We are not shopping servants, and these DC-DC converters are all over the marketplace. Use search terms like "12 volt DC-DC converter, etc. Look at the spec-sheet in detail _before_ you buy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Energy must be conserved, so, assuming a constant draw over time, power is going to be conserved. Therefore,

[Volts in] x [Amps in] = [Volts out] x [Amps out]

Of course, this does not account for losses in your voltage converter, but with a 12V car battery, you should be able to get 24V @ 1A with a 12V, 2+ A (a little more) input. 2A is easily doable with a car battery.

Based on you level of understanding, as demonstrated by the question, I would **not** recommend designing your own voltage booster. However, they are readily available at a reasonable price, like this one from Amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/Converter-Regulator-12v-Step-24v/dp/B0085T97PW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0085T97PW)

Alternatively, you could get a 24V battery...

Answer (score 0):

A voltage boosting circuit is what you'll find inside the DC-DC converter,  which is going to basically be a diode, coil, capacitor and a FET.  The FET is gonna apply 12V momentarily to your coil at x frequency,  the diode takes advantage of the collapsing magnetic field of the coil when the FET tuns off and (boosts) the voltage beyond the 12volts into the capacitor.  Doing this a couple thousand times per second keeps boosting the capacitor to a higher and higher voltage, so if you dont have a feedback loop or load draining the capacitor voltage, it could exceed the max voltage rating of the capacitor and blow up.  I would use a 555 timer and put an adjustable trimpot control comparator op-amp feedback loop attached to the reset pin for regulation and adjust it to 24V.